# How to show the mean or average value on a box plot with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have made the following graph:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [title = {Lengths of Amplification and Deletion Regions},ylabel = {$log_{10}(Length)$},
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2,3},
    xticklabels={Amplification, Deletion, Both},
    x tick label style={font=\footnotesize, text width=2.5cm, align=center}
    ]
    \addplot+[mark = *, mark options = {red},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=2.214844,
      lower quartile=3.608312,
      median=3.895478,
      upper quartile=4.447298,
      upper whisker=4.666284
    }, color = red
    ] coordinates{(0,4.832228)(0,5.513942)(0,6.29165)(0,5.216712)(0,5.677036)(0,4.981995)(0,5.172095)(0,4.056417)};
    \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {blue},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=3.508799,
      lower quartile=5.079821,
      median=5.481519,
      upper quartile=5.971588,
      upper whisker=6.250831
    }, color = blue
    ] coordinates{(0,6.508115)(0,6.486354)(0,6.860059)(0,6.620663)(0,7.312391)(0,7.357306)(0,6.421694)
    (0,6.479597)(0,6.690945)(0,6.661593)(0,7.271025)(0,6.396931)(0,7.035161)(0,7.371248)(0,7.033689)
    (0,7.002645)(0,6.590617)(0,7.171933)(0,6.416259)(0,5.552438)};
    \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {green},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=2.437751,
      lower quartile=3.334956,
      median=4.336029,
      upper quartile=5.068459,
      upper whisker=5.265037
    }, color = green
    ] coordinates{(0,5.826492)(0,5.819791)(0,6.21436)(0,4.47166)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

The circles near the median lines of each graph represents the average (log-transformed) for that respective group. I would like to make these dots into stars and to write the respective averages in parentheses, black colour: 4.06, 5.55, and 4.47.

Comment: I think you want the `average` key, which you can use in the same way as you are using (for example) the `median` key.  Then you can use the normal controls to customize its appearance.  By default it will appear as a diamond.

Comment: You also want to change that y-axis label to `\log_10{\hbox{Length}}`

Comment: @Thruston Hi! Could you please upload a small example? Could I insert text as well? Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the mean value on your box plot you can use the `average` key with `boxplot`.

I've only changed the middle bw plot, but you can see how to do the others.  I've also corrected the *y*-axis label.  Read [the manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), p.430-450 for how to add labels to the averages, and change the colour.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [title = {Lengths of Amplification and Deletion Regions},ylabel =
        {$\log_{10}(\hbox{Length})$},
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2,3},
    xticklabels={Amplification, Deletion, Both},
    x tick label style={font=\footnotesize, text width=2.5cm, align=center}
    ]
    \addplot+[mark = *, mark options = {red},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=2.214844,
      lower quartile=3.608312,
      median=3.895478,
      upper quartile=4.447298,
      upper whisker=4.666284
    }, color = red
    ] coordinates{(0,4.832228)(0,5.513942)(0,6.29165)(0,5.216712)(0,5.677036)(0,4.981995)(0,5.172095)(0,4.056417)};
    \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {blue},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=3.508799,
      lower quartile=5.079821,
      median=5.481519,
      average=5.442438,
      upper quartile=5.971588,
      upper whisker=6.250831
    }, color = blue
    ] coordinates{(0,6.508115)(0,6.486354)(0,6.860059)(0,6.620663)(0,7.312391)(0,7.357306)(0,6.421694)
    (0,6.479597)(0,6.690945)(0,6.661593)(0,7.271025)(0,6.396931)(0,7.035161)(0,7.371248)(0,7.033689)
    (0,7.002645)(0,6.590617)(0,7.171933)(0,6.416259)};
    \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {green},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=2.437751,
      lower quartile=3.334956,
      median=4.336029,
      upper quartile=5.068459,
      upper whisker=5.265037
    }, color = green
    ] coordinates{(0,5.826492)(0,5.819791)(0,6.21436)(0,4.47166)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add `average` to a boxplot that is made from a .csv? I get an unknown key error when I use `\addplot+[boxplot, average = 0.869, yticklabels={System 1}]`

Comment: @Hans feel free to ask a new question.  I think that the `prepared={...}` key is pretty essential to this solution.

Comment: @Hans, add `/boxplot/average={auto}`